# Receiving a string[] from another contract

Tags: arrays, string, tuples, solidity

I have the following sctructure:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.8.6;

contract Contract1 {

    struct authDataOSS {
        string oss;
        string mt_us;
        bool data_status;
    }

    struct ossName {
        string _name;
    }


 mapping (address => authDataOSS[]) private _allowedData;
 mapping (address => ossName[]) private _alllowedOSS;

function getOSS(address _usr_add) public view returns (address, ossName[] memory) {
       return (_usr_add, _alllowedOSS[_usr_add]);
    }

    
    function getDataUss(address _usr_add) public view returns (address, authDataOSS[] memory) {
        return(_usr_add, _allowedData[_usr_add]);
    }
}
```

Calling those functions directly from the contract "Contract1" everything works fine. But if I try to call from another contract i am facing the following issue: Type struct Contract1.ossName[] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type string[] memory. Here is the second contract:

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.6;

import './Contract1.sol';
 
contract Contract2 {
    
    event showMsg(uint);
    
    function list_data(Contract1 _contract1, address _usr_add) public view returns (address) {
        //(,bytes[] memory _data) = _contract1.getDataUss(_usr_add); this is the line with error
        (address _usr_add_res,) = _contract1.getDataUss(_usr_add);
        return (_usr_add_res);
    }

    function list_OSS(Contract1 _contract1, address _usr_add) public view returns (address) {
        //(,string[] memory _oss_names) = _contract1.getOSS(_usr_add); this is the line with error
        (address _usr_add_res,) = _contract1.getOSS(_usr_add);
        return (_usr_add_res);
    }
    
    
}
```

I'm try to finish the code and return a array in a tuple for the second contract.
Anyone knows how to receiving a tuple with a array and return! Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that you're receiving refers about value returned from methods called: `list_data()` and `list_OSS()`. The compiler said you that from the methods signatures inside in the first smart contract (Contract1) return values: `ossName[]` and `authDataOSS[]`. For this reason, it's impossible to cast this two value in `bytes[]` and `string[]` as you were doing.

In this specific case, you must create an interface for sharing the declaration about two structs (authDataOSS, ossName). At this point, you should implement the interface in both smart contracts, in details:

- In the first smart contract (Contract1) for using them into mappings and methods;
- In the second smart contract (Contract2) for change returns types inside signature methods and resolve your issue.

I shared in the following lines, how you should modify your smart contracts.

***Test.sol***

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.6;

interface DataStruct {
    struct authDataOSS {
        string oss;
        string mt_us;
        bool data_status;
    }

    struct ossName {
        string _name;
    }
} 

contract Contract1 is DataStruct {

    mapping (address => authDataOSS[]) private _allowedData;
    mapping (address => ossName[]) private _alllowedOSS;

    constructor() {
        _allowedData[msg.sender].push(authDataOSS("test", "test", true));
        _alllowedOSS[msg.sender].push(ossName("test"));
    }

    function getOSS(address _usr_add) public view returns (address, ossName[] memory) {
       return (_usr_add, _alllowedOSS[_usr_add]);
    }
    
    function getDataUss(address _usr_add) public view returns (address, authDataOSS[] memory) {
        return(_usr_add, _allowedData[_usr_add]);
    }
}
```

***Test1.sol***

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.6;

import "./Test.sol";
 
contract Contract2 is DataStruct {
    
    event showMsg(uint);
    
    function list_data(Contract1 _contract1, address _usr_add) public view returns (address, authDataOSS[] memory) {
        (address _usr_add_res, authDataOSS[] memory _data) = _contract1.getDataUss(_usr_add);
        return (_usr_add_res, _data);
    }

    function list_OSS(Contract1 _contract1, address _usr_add) public view returns (address, ossName[] memory) {
        (address _usr_add_res, ossName[] memory _oss_names) = _contract1.getOSS(_usr_add);
        return (_usr_add_res, _oss_names);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: It works! I saw a lot of examples on the internet telling me to iterate an array using a for but it didn't work. The correct way is as described in answer to this question. Thank You!